# How can I run an ajax call from another method in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

When I select an anchor tag in one of the child components it calls `pageChange` using on `onClick` event. This works. I want to call another method to trigger an ajax call to get the page data:

```
getPageData(slug){
    axios.get('http://ajax-call.com/'+slug)
    .then((response) => {
        console.log( response );
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}

pageChange(e){
    var slug = e.target.getAttribute('data-link');

    this.getPageData(slug);


    e.preventDefault();
}
```

I'm getting an error `Cannot read property 'getPageData' of null` I think I need to bind the method to `this` but I might be going down the wrong path here.

Comment: `.this((response) => {}` should be `.then((response) => {}`

Comment: Thanks for that catch. Still getting the error but that helps prevent a future one. Thanks!

Comment: What does `console.log(this)` log within `pageChange` function?

Comment: How is `pageChange` set to be called at code? You can use `Function.prototype.bind()` to bind an object as `this` within a function body `pageChange.bind(/* object that has getPageData property */)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just need to bind the function as you said. There is a nice shortcut way to do this:

```
pageChange = (e) => {
  var slug = e.target.getAttribute('data-link');

  this.getPageData(slug);

  e.preventDefault();
}
```

Which is roughly similar to binding it in the `componentDidMount`:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.pageChange = this.pageChange.bind(this);
}
```

Much more [info about events on the React site](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html) if you are inclined to read more about it.

Comment: I actually just added the `this.pageChange = this.pageChange.bind(this);` to my `componentDidMount()` which solved my issue. Thanks!